# Getting error on using aes(x = column), working perfectly with aes(x = dataset$column) in ggplo2, what package am I missing?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, tidyverse

> I think I am missing a particular package that's why I am getting an error

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, mapping = aes(x = SepalWidthCm, y = SepalLengthCm)) + geom_point()
```

**Console: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'SepalWidthCm' not found**

> This code below is working fine

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, mapping = aes(x = iris$SepalWidthCm, y = iris$SepalLengthCm)) + geom_point()
```

**Console: A scatter plot**

> What package am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't missing any packages. The `iris` data doesn't have column named `SepalWidthCm` or `SepalLengthCm` (I am not sure how you got the second line to work. Did you make those columns yourself?)

```
colnames(iris)

[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

So your code should look like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Resulting in:

[image: Iris scatter plot]